# Cleaning up a query with multiple LIKE options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's a simple query where I query cities based on their last letter:

```
SELECT city 
FROM stuff 
WHERE city LIKE '%a' 
   OR city LIKE '%b'
   OR city LIKE '%c'
```

I think I can do something like this:

```
SELECT city 
FROM stuff 
WHERE city LIKE ('%a', '%b', '%c')
```

But I can't get it to work. I've tried the `IN` operator as well.

Comment: This is probably going to be blasphemy for the SQL folks, but I would write the most broad query you can come up with, then do your fine grained filtering in your application code using LINQ and Regex, for example. Almost guaranteed to perform better, and will be a lot less time to develop and maintain.

Comment: What you are saying isn't blasphemy, it's just hard to defend. You don't need LINQ or another programming language to do something this simple. Its basic SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `LIKE` like an `IN`, but you can use the simple patten matching that SQL Server has:

```
SELECT city
FROM stuff
WHERE city LIKE '%[a-c]';
```

[LIKE (Transact-SQL) - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

Comment: I'm actually searching for other non-sequential letters in this case. I just used abc as examples.

Comment: They don't have to be sequential, @coinbird You could do `'%[aceji]'` if you wanted.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly your use case, I submit that it might not be worth the hassle.

LIKE matches need to retrieve the whole column for all records, even if an index is available, and that time outweighs the clause evaluation by at least one order of magnitude, possibly more.

Moreover, condensation of LIKE clauses (e.g. '%a', '%b', '%c' => %[a-c]') will:

- be difficult to maintain
- give rise to awkward corner cases (e.g. '%a' and '%in', but also just '%a', '%b' and '%e' would introduce complications, since '%[abe]' and '[%a-c]' use two different strategies)
- will *anyway* be unrolled at run time into effectively an OR set, *very probably the same you started with*, resulting in an overall *worse* performance.

The best you can hope to obtain is get rid of redundant clauses (e.g. '%na', '%a' => '%na' ). Doing this using server-side LIKE evaluators might turn out to be quadratic in the number of terms, and introduce latencies that would eat whatever gain could be obtained.

If you need to improve performances you might consider *storing an extra column* with, say, the city names in reverse (Tokyo => oykoT), adding the necessary `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers using `REVERSE()` (or writing the extra logic yourself). Looking for 'o%' is more index friendly than looking for '%o'.

Comment: Paul White has a good article about storing an extra column for things like this: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @stuff TABLE(City VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @stuff (City) VALUES ('Chicago'),('Aurora'),('Winamaic'),('Bloomfield');

SELECT      s.city 
FROM        @stuff AS s
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('%ra'),('Ch%'),('%aic')) AS pattern(pat)
WHERE       s.city LIKE pattern.pat;
```

**Returns:**

```
city
---------
Chicago
Aurora
Winamaic
```

**Quick Update**

The downside to this solution is it will slow down quick if you have a lot of long patterns. Depending on what you're doing, you may benefit from leveraging an indexed view. I've done something like this on a few occasions over the years with great success. Note my comments:

```
USE tempdb; -- On your own instance or a Dev box
GO
-- Table DDL and sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.places
(
    CityId INT IDENTITY, 
    City   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.patterns
(
    PatternID INT IDENTITY, 
    P         VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
GO    
INSERT dbo.places(City) VALUES ('Chicago'),('Aurora'),('Winamaic'),('Bloomfield');
INSERT dbo.patterns(P)   VALUES('%ra'),('Ch%'),('%aic')
GO

-- Indexed View
CREATE VIEW dbo.matchingCities
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT     places.CityId, places.City
FROM       dbo.places
CROSS JOIN dbo.patterns
WHERE      PATINDEX(patterns.P,places.City) > 0;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_CL__matchingCities ON dbo.matchingCities(CityId)
GO

-- Query:
SELECT mc.CityId, mc.City
FROM   dbo.matchingCities AS mc;
```

This returns the same thing but using a seek against my indexed view.

[image]